# Empty call to a callback in swift. How it can be useful?

Tags: swift

I had a glance at the AlamoFire lib code to learn something more about it and I've found this definition:

```
 var dataTaskDidReceiveData: ((NSURLSession!, NSURLSessionDataTask!, NSData!) -> Void)?
```

I suppose it defines that dataTaskDidReceiveData is a callback with some params and without a return.

Then I see that this callback is used in a "strange" way that I can't understand:

```
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession!, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        if let delegate = self[dataTask] as? Request.DataTaskDelegate {
            delegate.URLSession(session, dataTask: dataTask, didReceiveData: data)
        }

        dataTaskDidReceiveData?(session, dataTask, data)//??????
    }
```

How this call works exactly?

```
        dataTaskDidReceiveData?(session, dataTask, data)//??????
```

Answer (score 2):

`dataTaskDidReceiveData` is defined as optional closure. `?` is optional chaining operator. So `dataTaskDidReceiveData?(session, dataTask, data)` reads like: If `dataTaskDidReceiveData` is not nil call `dataTaskDidReceiveData` closure, else do nothing.